# "I mind to" vs "I am minded to"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context, differences, synonyms

If I wanted to say "I am inclined to seek cheaper results inside the supermarket", then which of the following ways would make the most sense?

> - I mind to seek cheaper results inside the supermarket
> - I am minded to seek cheaper results inside the supermarket.

According to google, the fifth definition of "mind" as a verb is "be inclined to do something" with the example: "he was minded to reject the application". This doesn't make sense because in that example, "minded" is an adjective (he *was* minded) — which I would assume to be, knowing the word "small-minded" — and also it is in the past tense of "mind".

Since I couldn't specifically tell what google meant by this, I went to the good ol' classic dictionary (with pages, *mind* you!) and found the words "mind" and "minded" to mean two seperate things.

*Minded* can mean "disposed, inclined; (in compounds) having a mind as described, e.g. small-minded" (I don't know what "in compounds" means, unfortunately). But the word *mind* does not mean any of those, as a noun or verb (transitive or intransitive).

I thus believe that the second sentence is (more) correct, but... did I evaluate correctly, or not? I mean, if "minded" is in past tense and could mean "be inclined to" then wouldn't "mind" just mean "incline to"? Because I'm still in Year 10 — I still undertake english studies, so I'm no real expert ;)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Nobody would ever say “seek cheaper results inside the supermarket”. What is that even supposed to mean? “In compounds” means just what it says: when you make compounds that end in _-minded_, that bit means ‘having a mind as described’, so _small-minded_ means ‘having a small mind’.

Comment: I’d say: “I always try to buy the cheapest things when I’m at the grocery store.”

Comment: Ok, guys, thanks. I wanted to sound formal, but I think I over-complicated it, hahaha.

Comment: Are you sure you're not thinking of "I'm of a mind to ..."?

Answer (score 4):

There may be some dialect that uses *I mind to* in that way, but I am not aware of one.

*I am minded to* feels old-fashioned to me, but certainly you still hear it where I live.

Answer (score 2):

From the [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/233927?rskey=2AAGSm&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid):

**minded**

> a. In predicative use only: intending, disposed, inclined to (†for
>   to) (do something). to be so minded: to be inclined to do what has
>   been mentioned or specified.

and the idiom:  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/if+you%27ve+a+mind+to+do)

**if you've a mind to do something**,

your second sentence is more correct:

*I am minded to seek cheaper results inside the supermarket.*

In AmE, **I have (I've) a mind to** or **I have in mind to** is occasionally heard and seen.